# Alternatives to VFIAX

Tags: investing, hsa

I've had some of my HSA invested in VFIAX, an s&p 500 passive fund and also fourth largest fund in the US.  My new HSA provider does not offer the fund. On offer are: VSIAX (Small value), VIGIX, VIIIX, VMVAX, VSMAX, and VVIAX.  Ideas for how to continue my index tracking? I can mix and match these in any percentage to recreate the VFIAX fund (which I have requested be added).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the funds listed VIIIX most closely matches VFIAX if you are still looking for a large cap index fund.

If you read the prospectus of each fund you'll find that they are both attempting to match the S&P 500 index as closely as possible.

Comment: I could mix and match to recreate was my thinking.

Comment: If you are trying to precisely match VFIAX, VIIIX is the correct choice. If you want small caps or mid caps, then you can add those to the allocation as desired, but no mixture of the above will get you closer to VFIAX than just allocating that amount to VIIIX.